# Is there callback received based on periodic subscription or only on change in subscribe() interface in android VHAL?

Tags: android, hal, asynccallback, android-binder, android-automotive

In Android VHAL, whether the interface subscribe(IVehicleCallback callback, vec options) provides callback to system service only when there is a change or based on subscription frequency if the VehiclePropertyChangeMode CONTINUOUS?

Reference link - https://source.android.com/docs/automotive/vhal/properties

I have seen only when there is change in subscribed property we get a callback

For example I am subscribing for 5 continuous properties for every 1 second, I am expecting a callback with 5 data every 1 sec, Can anyone explain me more on this?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.